# Trying to Combine Two Columns in the Where Clause

Tags: merge, concatenation, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two columns of data I want to join in the where clause so I can use the In function to query on it. I have a PROV_NUM (P00012546) and an AFF_NUM(0012).
I want to be able to say in my Where clause Where PROV_NUM + AFF_NUM in (P000125460012, P000145890003)
I am trying to merge the two columns in the where clause so I can copy and paste a list of PROV and AFF numbers as one number and query the combined two strings.

I have tried to concat as well as merge with no luck. I am using Teradata SQL Assistant.

Comment: What error are you getting? Show what you are doing. `WHERE PROV_NUM||AFF_NUM IN ('P000125460012', 'P000145890003')` would be legal syntax, at least

Comment: Thank you! That worked.